# Search with autocomplete and Ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, ajax, autocomplete

I want to make a search like them from google.

I've made it this far, that I can show all data from the database in my textbox with using a webservice. Thats my code:

**Webform.aspx**

```
<%--**Start Search**--%>
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    <Services><asp:ServiceReference Path="~/WebService.asmx" /></Services>
</asp:ScriptManager>
<%--Search-Textbox--%>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtSearchInput" Width="100%" />
<asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Suche" onclick="btnSearch_Click" />
<%--Autocomplete (Ajax)--%>
<asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoComplete1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtSearchInput"
   ServiceMethod="GetNames" ServicePath="~/WebService.asmx" MinimumPrefixLength="1"  
   EnableCaching="true" CompletionInterval="1000" CompletionSetCount="20">
</asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
<%--**End Search**--%>
```

**Webservice.asmx**

```
[WebMethod]
public string[] GetNames(string prefixText, int count)
{
    List<string> items = new List<string>(count);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CSLinker"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(cs))
    {
        string sql = "SELECT Name FROM tabProjects WHERE Name LIKE '" + prefixText + "%' UNION all SELECT Name FROM tabLinks WHERE Name LIKE '" + prefixText + "%'";
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
        adapter.Fill(ds);
    }

    foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        items.Add(dr["Name"].ToString());
    }
    return items.ToArray();
}
```

My problem now is, that i only have the name from the database. But for the search I need also the ID. Can somebody say me, how I can also query the ID without showing it in the textform? 
I hope you can understand my problem. My english isnt' so good...

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just pass the project name as the parameter rather than the probject ID? If you are using Response.Redirect I am assuming the user selects a project from the list of selections and the code behind handles somekind of event:

```
    public void onProjectSelected()
    {
        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CSLinker"].ConnectionString;
        string projectName = txtSearchInput.Text;
        int projectID = 0;
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT ProjectID FROM TabProjects WHERE Name = @Name", connection))
            {
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50)).Value = projectName;
                connection.Open();
                if (int.TryParse(command.ExecuteScalar().ToString(), out projectID))
                {
                    Response.Redirect(string.Format("?ProjectID={0}", projectID));
                }
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
        //Handle project not found events here
    }
```

Also **USE PARAMATERISED QUERIES** otherwise [SQL Injection](http://bobby-tables.com/) could ruin your day!

If I were to type "It's a test" into your text box you would end up with an invalid SQL statement as the apostrophe I have used will result in the following SQL.

```
SELECT Name FROM tabProjects WHERE Name LIKE 'It's a test%'
```

Which clearly won't run and will not be a great user experience for anyone using your website. More seriously though, if I were to type into the text box on your page `'; DROP TABLE TabProjects --` you may find, depednding on the permissions assigned to the CSLinker connection string, that you no longer have an tabProjects table as this is the SQL that is run:

```
SELECT Name FROM tabProjects WHERE Name LIKE ''; DROP TABLE tabProjects -- %'
```

You should use something like this for your web method:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public string[] GetNames(string prefixText, int count)
    {
        List<string> items = new List<string>();
        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CSLinker"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SET ROWCOUNT @Count SELECT Name FROM TabProjects WHERE Name LIKE @Name + '%'", connection))
            {
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50)).Value = prefixText;
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Count", SqlDbType.Int, 8)).Value = count;
                connection.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        items.Add(reader.GetString(0));
                    }
                }
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
        return items.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: @GarethD you are assume project name as unique, if project name unique here why OP wants ID field!

Comment: @Damith That is a good point, however if project name is not unique how will the user know which of the 2 projects appearing in the autocomplete to select?

Comment: @GarethD I had thought the same. In my portal I have the luck, that all projects have an unique name so your solution works fine for me. But I would be very interested, if someone has a "cleaner" solution. Btw: Thanks for the explanation of the "parameterised queries".I had never before thought at his security problem (fortunately its a intranet-application).

Comment: I have not tried the Ajax toolkit method that @Damith mentioned in his answer, but from what I can tell I would say this is the best solution short of building your own custom solution. I have actually upvoted his answer as I think it is better than mine. You are welcome for the advice on parameterised queries, even on an intranet application they should be used, there are more reasons other than SQL injection to use them (typed parameters, not data loss through string truncation, and more legible code).